# Linux Character Device Modules: Why do we need both *owner and MOD_INC_USE_COUNT?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, driver, kernel-module

I am currently studying character device modules (drivers) and I am bewildered as to why there is both a use count and a *owner (in the file operations struct).

As can be seen in the following link, the file operations struct is:

```
struct file_operations {
       struct module *owner;
       loff_t (*llseek) (struct file *, loff_t, int);
       ssize_t (*read) (struct file *, char *, size_t, loff_t *);
       ssize_t (*write) (struct file *, const char *, size_t, loff_t *);
       int (*readdir) (struct file *, void *, filldir_t);
       unsigned int (*poll) (struct file *, struct poll_table_struct *);
       int (*ioctl) (struct inode *, struct file *, unsigned int, unsigned long);
       int (*mmap) (struct file *, struct vm_area_struct *);
       int (*open) (struct inode *, struct file *);
       int (*flush) (struct file *);
       int (*release) (struct inode *, struct file *);
       int (*fsync) (struct file *, struct dentry *, int datasync);
       int (*fasync) (int, struct file *, int);
       int (*lock) (struct file *, int, struct file_lock *);
         ssize_t (*readv) (struct file *, const struct iovec *, unsigned long,
          loff_t *);
         ssize_t (*writev) (struct file *, const struct iovec *, unsigned long,
          loff_t *);
    };
```

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/c577.htm

As we were taught in class, the *owner is used to ensure that the module isn't unloaded if there is a device still using it.
However, further down the article in the link above, they describe that this is accomplished through the use of macros such as MOD_INC_USE_COUNT.

Therefore, my question is: why do we need both? Do the macros use the pointer in order to access this counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incrementing module's usage counter requires module's structure to be in use.

Macro `MOD_INC_USE_COUNT` indirectly uses `THIS_MODULE` pointer, which corresponds to the **currently compiled** module. In other words, for increment module's usage counter with this macro, you need to call it from the **module's code**.

From the other side, file operations are issued from *outside of the module* (in Virtual FileSystem layer, VFS). So prevention of the module's unloading should be performed **outside of the module**, otherwise race conditions are unavoidable [Think about calling `.open` function from outside of the module and module's unloading at the same time]. That is why `.owner` field is needed.

---

Modern kernel doesn't have macro `MOD_INC_USE_COUNT`. Instead, it defines function

```
void __module_get(struct module* mod);
```

which *directly* accepts module parameter.